# Print .pdf files in Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: pdf, windows-mobile-6.5, zebra-printers, motorola, handheld

I recently got a Motorola MC9190 handheld and a Zebra P4T printer. The Motorola has a Windows Mobile 6.5 version. My problem is that I want to print .pdf files but any apps can do it. I installed PrintBoy v7 but the service server for convert .pdf files is down, also, I installed ActivePrint Traveler but the app can't check my registration.

Anyone has a solution for my problem?
I only want to print .pdf files with my printer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems are:

1. Windows Mobile does not come with any system printer support
2. the P4T is a mobile receipt Bluetooth? printer not designed to print PDF files

PrintBoy and any other mobile client/server printing application may help, but better you do not use PDF. If possible create print files in native printer language (ZPL for Zebra?) and send these directly to the printer.